# Should I use MergeOption.NoTracking when I want to retrieve data just for display?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Lets say I want to display some data on webpage, so I Load the data:

```
using (KEntities ctx = new KEntities())
{
    ctx.KSet.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;

    var items = (from c in ctx.KSet
                 where c.ParentId == 0
                 select new
                 {
                     Title = c.Title,
                     Id = c.Id,                           
                     Subs = ctx.KSet.Where(o => o.ParentId == c.Id)                                      
                 }).ToList();

 }
```

Is there any benefit using MergeOption.NoTracking?
If now, when should I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you only want the data, then use MergeOption.NoTracking. This means they wont be stored in the graph that keeps track of the entity for updating and deleting. This helps performance alittle in terms of memory.

Comment: please note, that i am disposing the context each time i retrieve data, does it change anything?

Comment: No, you still take a performance hit, even though the graph is managed by the context.